# How can I loop through all the .py files in my current directory & import a variable from each one?

Tags: python

I am in a file called `end.py`.

In my current directory I have x number of `.py` files.

Each of these .py files returns a variable called `total`.

Is it possible, in `end.py`, to loop through all `.py` files in the current directory (apart from itself - `end.py`) and import each file's `total` variable & ultimately store the value of each `total` variable in a list to be used later on in `end.py`?

Comment: Yes, that's possible

Comment: @Wombatz: That's an incorrect way of answering the question. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragmatics -- it is understood that the question is really "how", even though this is not explicitly spelled out.

Comment: How about reg expressions and a nested for loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can list the Python files in the current directory:

```py
import pathlib

source_files = pathlib.Path('.').glob('*.py')
```

Using importlib, you can import these in a loop:

```py
import importlib.util
import pathlib

for source_file in pathlib.Path('.').glob('*.py'):
    name = source_file.stem
    spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(name, source_file)
    mod = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
    spec.loader.exec_module(mod)
```

In the `for` loop, you can access the `total` as `mod.total`.

To skip a single file, like `end.py`, you can add:

```py
import importlib.util
import pathlib

for source_file in pathlib.Path('.').glob('*.py'):
    name = source_file.stem
    if name == 'end':
        continue
    spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(name, source_file)
    mod = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
    spec.loader.exec_module(mod)
```

Note that this will import every module in the current directory. Does that include the current module? You will probably want to skip that one too.

### Documentation

- [`Path.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob)
- [`spec_from_file_location`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.util.spec_from_file_location)
- [`module_from_spec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.util.module_from_spec)

Comment: Did you mean to include the source_files var in the for loop or was that just a demonstration?

Comment: @fkay: The second piece of code is supposed to stand on its own.

Comment: thanks, was just curious as a beginner since this is the first time I've seen an iterable defined that way.

Comment: @tonitone120: You may be recursively importing the main module. Try skipping it.

Comment: yes you're right that must be what happened. I tried to delete my comment as I figured this out. Thank-you.